# What is the reason of using strip_tag or a write list for text input

Tags: php, security, xss

I know they are both use for prevent XSS attack.  But when i use htmlspecialchars , it seems just ok. `<script>` and `<?php ?>` would be displayed on the screen. It means they are not functioning, right?
So, my question is , is htmlspecialchars enough for preventing XSS.
If so, what is the reason using strip_tag or a white list of tag?

Comment: This is primarely opinion based. Some websites need to display tags in their comments, others don't want the tags in the comments. It all depends on what your website is about.

Comment: htmlspecialchars should do pretty much what you need, excepting in special circumstances

Answer (score 0):

`htmlspecialchars` is safe enough. It is very common as it displays the same as the user typed, but makes it harmless. `strip_tags` takes all the tags away, is usefull for alot of other things.

Comment: `htmlentities()` covers a bit more, which protects against `javascript:` URLs ;)